# SQLite.Net PCL support / workaround for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a WIndows Phone 8.1 application and I want to use the SQLite.Net PCL library forked oysteinkrog here: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL
However, when I'm trying to create a new connection I do not have all properties needed to create a `SQLiteConnectionWithLock`
I have found this:

```
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(new Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>(()=>new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), new SQLiteConnectionString(databasePath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false))));
```

But the new SQLitePlatformWinRT does not apply and I can't seem to find an alternative for WP8.1
Any thoughts on a workaround for this?

Answer (score -1):

It's compatible the WinRT with the phone, as they wrote it here:
[SQLite.Net.Platform for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506374/sqlite-net-platform-for-windows-phone-8-1)
and in this comment: [SQLite.Net-PCL Connection not finding the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523763/sqlite-net-pcl-connection-not-finding-the-db) . So you don't need to worry about it, only use as other cases.

EDIT: Make sure you added sqlite3.dll from sqlite.org for windows phone 8.1 WinRT manually.