# SQLite.Net.Platform for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, platform, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I can't find any `SQLite.Net.Platform` library that works with **Windows Phone 8.1**.

These are not working:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.WindowsPhone8/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.Generic/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.Win32/

Any workaround?

Comment: Go to the following blog entry and go through the tutorial it should work http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/05/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-2/

Comment: @StuartSmith, Thanks but that doesn't work with "Foreign Key" solutions. So I have to use another library (SQLite-Net Extensions) that needs the Platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinRT platform](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/tree/master/src/SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT) is compatible with Windows Phone 8.1 projects. You can copy the sources to your platform specific project and instantiate the connection using `SQLitePlatformWinRT` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Plz edit your post that we have to copy the WinRT source code in our project for the moment.

Comment: Hello! 
Could one of you maybe explain how one copies SQLitePlatformWinRT-source-code to the phone-project from the windows-project. Glad to see it can be done!

Comment: @user2915962 In your shared project you use the SQLite-Net PCL nuget package and then you download the sources from the link in the answer and copy those files to your Windows Phone 8.1 project to instantiate your SQLite connection

Comment: I used the nuget SQLite-Net PCL in my PCL. Then I created a new folder in my wp81-project and named it SQL. I then downloaded the files from the link. Is that the right way? I get loads of errors. In the link there are also a file: SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.csproj. Should I use that one? Thank you